# Swapping rows for a column that has unique constraint

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using postgresql and sequelize to do my db operations

Suppose I have a person table like this:

```
id (pkey) | name | email (unique) | company
1         | john | john@x.com     |  abc
2         | mary | mary@y.com     |  abc
3         | will | NULL           |  xyz
```

I make the unique constraint like this:

```
const PersonData = sequelize.define(
    'users',
    {
      ....
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: {
          args: true,
          msg: 'Email already in use!',
        },
      },
      ....
      },
```

I'm getting payload like

```
{{
    id: 1,
    email: mary@y.com
},
{
    id: 2,
    email: john@x.com
}}
```

I want to swap the emails for id 1 and id 2 here. How can I do that using sequelize?

The output I want:

```
id (pkey) | name | email (unique) | company
1         | john | mary@y.com     |  abc
2         | mary | john@x.com     |  abc
3         | will | NULL           |  xyz
```

Comment: did you try using transactions? https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#unmanaged-transactions

Comment: Please update your question to include your current query.  It seems the emails have been reversed, you are just not getting the all columns in result.

Comment: You definitely need a transaction and this unique constraint should be applied only on COMMIT (should be indicated on creation of this constraint).

Comment: @Belayer I'm sorry I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Anatoly How to 'indicate' that?

Comment: For that you need to show how you created this unique constraint.

Comment: @Anatoly I have edited my question to include that

Comment: Did you check if you have any unique constraints in the table that reflect this defined uniqueness. I suppose if you used `sync` to create the table then you need to define a unique index in the model.

Comment: My table does show this to be a unique key. its also a foreign key btw, associated with another table. So the pgadmin shows it as both